# Share javascript code between web apps

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2, es6-modules

I'm working on two web applications (one for desktop and one for mobile) that will share (hopefully) 80% of the code.

I'm using ES6 modules and webpack for creating the JS bundles.

Now, sharing code is the easy part. The problem is with the code that is not shared. the code that is different in each app.

For example, let's say I have two javascript files:

app.js (shared between different contexts - web and mobile):

```
import foo from './foo';

// ...
```

foo.js (web):

```
export default foo = () => {
    //do some web logic ...
}
```

foo.js (mobile):

```
export default foo = () => {
    //do some mobile logic ...
}
```

note that `app.js` is shared between the apps and it uses `foo.js` that has different implementation in each app. I want to create two bundles, one with each implementation.

What is the correct way to handle this kind of situation?

I can think of something like in React Native - creating two files with suffix:
`foo.web.js`
`foo.mobile.js`
but still import them by the same path: `./foo`; and create two bundles using webpack, and take the correct file according to the type of the app.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can use any file structure you like, you just have to get webpack to resolve the chosen module names to the respective files.